# bootstrap img responsive height does not keep container height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an image that want to be responsive to the container size.
The parent container (cover-photo) has a height of 180px.
The image has a height of 853px. However when using img-fluid, the image does not keep the container height of 180px instead it keeps its own height of 853px.

```html
              <!doctype html>
              <html lang="en">
                <head>
                  <title>Hello, world!</title>
                  <!-- Required meta tags -->
                  <meta charset="utf-8">
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

                  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
                  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
               

                 <style>
                   .cover-photo {
                      height: 180px;
                    }
                   </style>
                      
                </head>
                <body>
                 <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="container">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="cover-photo">
                          <img class="img-fluid" src="http://newlovewallpapers.in/images/hd-love-images-and-wallpaper/hd-love-images-and-wallpaper-11-1280.jpg" alt="Background profile">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                
                  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
                  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
                  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                  <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
                  <script src="js/parallax.js"></script>
                </body>
              </html>
```

I understand that img-fluid in Bootstrap is max-width: 100%; and height: auto; and are applied to the image so that it scales with the parent element. But in this case it does not scale to the parent height.
Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: try the image  as background image for that container

Comment: Yes, that works. But in this case I need to use it as img since the image will be changed by a user, think it as about the profile background such facebook banner and it's profile picture.

Comment: u can use the image as per the container width and height, thats make the full view for that image. Otherwise put overflow: hidden; for .cover-photo, then image not overflow with that div. another way use the background property in html and u can change image using "attribute" something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning

You need to give following CSS to img-fluid class

```
 .img-fluid {    
        max-height: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }
```